# Create a workspace with different PATH ubuntu

Tags: linux, ubuntu, machine-learning, workspace

Hello i am reading a ML (Machine learning) book. And i got a bit confused.
Currently i am in the part that says "Create the workspace". It actually goes like this:
"Next you need to create a workspace directory for your Machine Learning code and datasets.Open a Terminal and type the following commands(after the $ prompts):"

```
$ export ML_PATH="$HOME/ml"  #You can change the path if you prefer
$ mkdir -p $ML_PATH
```

After that creates an isolated environment and at the end it says:
"Now every time you want to activate this enviroment, just open a terminal and type

```
$ cd $ML_PATH
$ source env/bin/activate
```

I do so and i works like a charm.But if i open a new terminal it does not work .Could someone explain me what is wrong ?? 
Thank you in advance!
P.S the book is "Hands-On Machine learning with Scikit-Learn & TensorFlow" 
By O'REILLY and Aurelien Geron

Comment: they forgot to tell you that the `export` goes in your `.bash_profile`

Comment: `.bashrc`, to be precise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Run the following command in your terminal:

```
echo "export ML_PATH='$HOME/ml'" >> ~/.bashrc
```

It will append the required export statement to your .bash_profile file, which is used to create aliases like you need to. Please note that it is `>>`, and not `>`.

If you want to see the update right now, do:

```
source ~/.bashrc
```

Comment: Hello! Thank you for your time! 
I did this,  but i edited the  .profile  file and under my current PATH 
PATH="$HOME/bin:$HOME/.local/bin:$PATH"
 i added 
{ML_PATH="$HOME/ml"}
i did
{source .profile} 
but if i reopen a terminal and { echo $ML_PATH } i get nothing .

Comment: First of all it should be  >    ~/.profile right ?? 
I use ubuntu 16.04

Comment: No, it should be exactly as the command says, i.e., `.bash_profile`!

Comment: But there is no ' .bash_profile' in ubuntu 16.04 there is .profile instead

Comment: Ok, my bad! Change the filename to `.bashrc`. I am updating the answer.

Comment: Sorry to bother you again. But is there any chances to be the  `.profile` file?
Beacause i used  ` vim ~/.bashrc` 
 and i didnt find my current `PATH`  so i could add the ` ML_PATH` underneath it !

Comment: It is not mandatory to add `ML_PATH` beneath `PATH`. They are independent.

Comment: So i basically i just add the `ML_PATH` in the end of the `.bashrc` file?
And nothing to the `.profile` file??

Comment: That would be sufficient. .bashrc file is one of the files read for environment variables and some other stuff.

Comment: So in every workspace in which i want different path i just put the `PATH` in the `bashrc` file.Right??

Comment: Yes. This logic can be extended to other scenarios also. When modifying the `PATH` variable, just make sure you append/prepend and not overwrite it.

Comment: Ok. Thank you so much for your time !